# Error when writing in colour with C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the console text coloured with C# using:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red();
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Non-invocable member '`System.ConsoleColor.Red`' cannot be used like a method.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you read the error message? ConsoleColor.Red() isn't a method.

Comment: [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) and look at the examples. Did you even read the error message? If you did and didn't understand it, did you google it to try and understand what it is and why it is happening? Please take some basic steps to figure this out for yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ConsoleColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx) is an enum and `Red` is a field of that enum representing a particular value. You can't invoke like you would a method. Try removing the parentheses:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

Answer (score 3):

[`ConsoleColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an enumeration. parentheses are used for method calls in C#. Remove them and just access the member:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```